# OpenRefine Multiply Header Rows

Tags: openrefine

I have a `csv` file with some data in for multiply years. In the ultimate wisdom of the data provider the data is structured with is in effect multiply header rows (one for each year).

For *example* at the top of the file I have:

```
All | 2004 | Team | Player then some other rows
```

Then after all the data for 2004 there is another header row that looks like:

```
All | 2005 | Team | Player
```

Is there a way in `OpenRefine` to sort this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand it, your data is structured in this way.

```
All,2004,Team,Player

1, data1,team1,Player1

2, data2,team2,Player2

3, data3,team3,Player3

All,2005,Team,Player

4, data4,team4,Player4
```

If this is correct, one possible solution would be to create a "year" column and then delete the headers. Here is a possibility using the regular expression `^\d{4}$` to isolate the years.

[image]

Comment: Thanks really helpful.